# amazon-ec2 -> php mail()?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendmail, spam

I am running a PHP website on an amazon EC2 Ubuntu server.

I would like to use PHP's mail() function for sending a few admin notification emails per day.

First the mail() function didn't work.

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Now it works but I wonder if this is safe? Can my server be used for spam now?

Edit:
No I don't wan't to send spam. :) I don't really know what postfix/sendmail does on the server. My fear was that it installs some open SMTP service which is open to spammers if I don't secure it somehow but I guess this isn't true?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer is tested on Amazon EC2, both on Ubuntu and Amazon modified Fedora. Comes with very useful methods, i suggest you to use it.

Comment: Are the recipients of these emails subscribers, or is it just yourself (ie, notification emails)? How many emails do you need to send per day or per second? I've just noticed the tag 'spam'; are you intending to send spam?

Comment: I guess on average about 5 mails per day to a fixed administrator adress. No I don't wan't to send spam. :) I don't really know what postfix/sendmail does on the server. My fear was that it installs some open SMTP service which is open to spammers if I don't secure it somehow but I guess this isn't true?